# Variable number of objects instantiated from a structure/class

Tags: c++, class, structure

I need to define a structure (or class) in c++ which has a fixed number of data/function members. Though the number of instances made from this class needs to increase or decrease (and I do not know how many instances I need, that's determined on the fly). An example is a class "book" with data members: "cost", "author", etc. but the number of books in the library can increase/decrease as people borrow/bring back books. So I cannot use something like:

```
book *pointer = new book[3]
```

As I am not sure if I will have 3 books.

Please guide me on what kind of strategy I should take.

Answer (score 0):

You can store

```
std::vector<book> books
```

[vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) has [resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I explored the vector, it actually does what I wanted. Also, I saw that I can use a sort() function on the vector. But here, if I want to sort the vector elements (which are structures themeselves) not neccessarily based on the first member of each structure element, what should I do? does the sort function have an argument to tell it to sort the vector of structure based on the ith data member of the structure elements?

Comment: @user2225868: There are two options. One, overload operator < for your struct. Second, write a function returning bool and taking two objects of your struct. The function should return true if and only if the first object is less (should come first in the sorted order). Then pass that function as the third argument to sort